About perfect fields and totally inseparable extensions
$(\star)$ Let  $L = F(x)$ be the field of rational functions over a perfect field $F$  of characteristic  $p$ . Let  $K = F(f)$  for some rational function  $f$ . Prove that  $L/L_{T.I}$   is separable.
$ \bullet$ $L_{T.I}=\{x \in L:x \text{ is totally inseparable on\}  K}=\{x∈L:x^{p^{m}}∈K \text{ for some  } m≥0\}$.
$ \bullet$ Ideas : It is easy to prove that $x$ is algebraic on $K$, and by the primitive element theorem we can say that $L_{T.I} = F(f, g)$ with $f$ and $g$ rational functions. But i don't know how to continue.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hint: The following assumes that $f$ is a polynomial, but the same idea would work for rational function as well.
It suffices to show that $x$ is separable over $L_{T.I}$. Let
$$y = f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n \in F[x],$$
and write $K = F(y)$. Note that $f(u) - y \in K[u]$ has $x$ as a root, though it may not be the minimal polynomial of $x$.

If $f'(u) \not\equiv 0$, then $f(u) - y$ is separable, and we are done.
If $f'(u) \equiv 0$, then $f(u)$ is of the form
$$f(u) = b_0 + b_1 u^p + \cdots + b_n u^{pn} \in F[u]$$
As $F$ is perfect, we can write each $b_i = c_i^p$ for some $c_i \in F$. So actually
$$f(u) = (c_0 + c_1u + \cdots + c_nu^n)^p$$
Hence if we set $y_1 = c_0 + c_1x + \cdots + c_nx^n$, then $y_1 \in L_{T.I}$ by definition, since $y_1^p = f(x) = y \in K$. Now if we let $f_1(u) = c_0 + c_1 u + \cdots + c_n u^n \in F[u]$, then $f_1(u) - y_1 \in L_{T.I}[u]$ with $x$ being a root. Now we can play the same game again, with $f_1(u) - y_1$ in place of $f(u) - y$.

Since $f(x)$ has finite degree to start with, this game would terminate in finite steps, so at some point you will find a separable polynomial over $L_{T.I}$, with $x$ as a root, QED.
